# Update Rows in SSIS OLEDB Destination

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a data flow process where I have an OLEDB Source and an OLEDB Destination like below:

[image: Data Flow Task]

Source merges data from two staging tables and returns a result set (say, 50K rows). These 50K rows are present in the destination table as well but are old data.

```
SELECT * FROM staging1
UNION
SELECT * FROM staging2
```

Generally, in the OLEDB destination we insert the returned dataset from the source to destination table, but in my case I have to update the old 50K rows with these new 50K rows.

Kind of a bulk update.

Can anyone please let me know how I can do that? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, found a solution to my problem; Updating all rows using a SQL query and a SQL Task in SSIS Like Below. May help others if they face same challenge in future.

```
update Original 
set Original.Vaal= t.vaal 
from Original join (select * from staging1  union   select * from staging2) t 
on Original.id=t.id
```

Comment: I was thinking this myself.  Why go through the hassle of selecting to a staging table, and then updating from the staging table, when you can just use a Script Task to  create a single SQL statement that selects and updates?

Comment: There is merit to the SSIS and intermediate table technique if your data source and destination are on separate servers. Doing this took my sync process down from 50 minutes to 2, which is pretty great.

Answer (score 46):

You can't do a bulk-update in SSIS within a dataflow task with the OOB components.

The general pattern is to identify your inserts, updates and deletes and push the updates and deletes to a staging table(s) and after the Dataflow Task, use a set-based update or delete in an Execute SQL Task. Look at Andy Leonard's [Stairway to Integration Services series](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/updating-rows-in-incremental-loads-level-4-of-the-stairway-to-integration-services). Scroll about 3/4 the way down the article to "Set-Based Updates" to see the pattern.

Stage data

[image: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Images/11369.png]

Set based updates

[image]

You'll get much better performance with a pattern like this versus using the `OLE DB Command` transformation for anything but trivial amounts of data.

If you are into third party tools, I believe CozyRoc and I know PragmaticWorks have a merge destination component.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer/confirmation I was looking for; a straightforward NO :). Bad luck, can't go for any third party tools.

Comment: @statikuz I agree, but with https://www.guerrillamail.com/ it only takes a few seconds

Comment: sqlservercentral is worth the registration, IMHO. I also agree with @Turch about using a temporary email service. Keeps your inbox clean. Alternatively you can simply unsubscribe from their email list after you register.

Comment: For anyone looking for the Stairway to Integration Services link above, it has moved to here: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/adding-rows-in-incremental-loads-level-3-of-the-stairway-to-integration-services

Comment: The relevant Stairway to Integration services link is now https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/updating-rows-in-incremental-loads-level-4-of-the-stairway-to-integration-services

Answer (score 22):

Use Lookupstage to decide whether to insert or update.
Check this link for more info - http://beingoyen.blogspot.com/2010/03/ssis-how-to-update-instead-of-insert.html

Steps to do update:

1. Drag OLEDB Command [instead of oledb destination]
2. Go to properties window
3. Under Custom properties select SQLCOMMAND and insert update command ex:

   UPDATE table1 SET col1 = ?, col2 = ? where id = ?
4. map columns in exact order from source to output as in update command

Comment: rs, read my question again; I already know it has to be update and no need to decide. Just want to know, how do I go about updating a bulk rocords.

Comment: did you read that article? It will tell how to generate a script to update rows and also concept about how you can update in SSIS

Comment: Rahul is correct. The linked article will perform singleton updates for all 50k rows. That's going to be slow and painful. Their desire is to issue a single update statement that merges the data in one fell swoop.

Comment: then this can be done using "execute sql task" where he can write script to select and update or use stored procedure, there is no option to do bulk update using source and destinations in data flow tab. Data flow task process row by row

Comment: Though this is not the solution I was not looking for but +1 for providing the alternative.

Comment: I was trying to rebuild the data flow as in link from RS. but I just can not find the object UPDATE in the toolbox. Can anyone help where to find this?