# Changing ETL to incremental Load

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis, etl, msbi

I am new to make etl packages, and I’m learning things exploring the packages in visual studio.
I was given a task that involves involve taking the current logic in the ETL from the merge statement and redesigning the ETL to have a functioning Initial and incremental load path.  I have searched the internet enough but couldn’t find a proper answer. Please direct me how to proceed with this.

Pasted the Merge query below by removing all the attributes and keeping only 3 for understanding purpose.
How to get rid of this merge and use INIT and INCR Load (which I want to add in the data flow).
Let me know if any further details or info is missing. Sry if this is a noob question.

The Merge statement is of the format:

```
MERGE INTO <DestTableName> AS DIM
USING (
SELECT
    Cast(EF.Form_PK as nvarchar(50)) FormSourceId
    ,EF.FormName
    ,CASE WHEN EF.FormStatus = 1 THEN N'Active' ELSE N'Inactive' END  FormStatus

FROM <Tables and Joins>
) AS SRC
ON  SRC.FormSourceID = DIM.FormSourceID
WHEN MATCHED And (
Coalesce(SRC.FormName, '') <> Coalesce(DIM.FormName, '')
OR Coalesce(SRC.FormStatus, '') <> Coalesce(DIM.FormStatus, '')
                )   
THEN
UPDATE SET
    DIM.FormName  =  SRC.FormName
    ,DIM.FormStatus  =  SRC.FormStatus
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (
    FormSourceId
    ,FormName
    ,FormStatus
    )
VALUES  (
    SRC.FormSourceId
    ,SRC.FormName
    ,SRC.FormStatus
)

  WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND DimEvaluationId <> -1 THEN
DELETE;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10557503/181965

Comment: One commonly-used way to do an incremental load is with the Lookup Transformation.

Comment: It's not clear why you need 2 separate ETL paths for initial versus incremental load.  During initial load <DestTableName> will be empty and the MERGE will handle it correctly - every row will meet the WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET condition and will be inserted.

Comment: @pw : That is a standard and we are modifying every etl pckg to that standard.